# Check box in gridview should update the splistitem check box

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, gridview

I am a newbie in visual studio. I have a Sharepoint list which contains the following fields group name, user, section and active(which is a check box) . I have a grid view visual web part which will retrieve the values from the list, and I need a check box in the grid view.

When the user selects the check box in grid view and click on the Ok button , I want the SharePoint list item Active to get updated as True or Yes and unchecks and clicks Ok as False or No.

The following is what I have done so far. I am able to retrieve values from the list . but when i click on the check box nothing gets updated in my SharePoint list.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="false">   

<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Group Name" HeaderText="Group Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="true" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#ad0015">


<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                  Width="100px"/>
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">

<HeaderTemplate>
</HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Ok" 
Width="119px" />




protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    DataTable GetData()
    {
        SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb oWeb = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
        SPList oSPList = oWeb.Lists["sample"];
        SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection = oSPList.Items;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Group Name", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("User", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Active", typeof(bool));
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            DataRow dataRow;
            foreach (SPListItem oSplistItem in oSPListItemCollection)
            {
                dataRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                dataRow["Group Name"] = oSplistItem["Group Name"].ToString();
                dataRow["User"] = oSplistItem["User"].ToString();
                dataRow["Section"] = oSplistItem["Section"].ToString();
                //dataRow["ID"] = oSplistItem["ID"].ToString();
                //   dataRow["Active"] = oSplistItem["Active"].ToString();

            }


            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Managers Approval" + ex.Message.ToString());
            return dt;
        }
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            // Access the CheckBox
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkStatus");
            bool status = cb.Checked;
            string strBoolean = Convert.ToString(status);
                    if (cb != null)
                    {
                        SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;

                        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            SPList oSPList = oWeb.Lists["sample"];
                            SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection = oSPList.Items;
                            foreach (SPListItem oSplistItem in oSPListItemCollection)
                            {
                                if (strBoolean == "True")
                                {
                                    oSplistItem["Active"] = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    oSplistItem["Active"] = false;
                                }
                                oSplistItem.Update();
                            }

                        }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note, that Stackexchange has a site for all Sharepoint related problems: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: Also are you trying to update specific item? If yes then you need to add hidden input field with list item id and in your checked event get this id and update only item with this id.

Comment: I have added the input field . it is 'Active'

Comment: I have got it working for one row with, but its not working for each row in the grid view . I will add the modified code above

Comment: Unfortunately there are no errors

Comment: Thank you i got it working by adding the list item id, but only administrators are able to do. How can a person with read only access be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     uncomment the following lines 
>      1. uncomment the following lines
>      2. //   dataRow["Active"] = oSplistItem["Active"].ToString();
>      3.  in your button_click event, get the row id
>      4.  give the id to the splistitem and it will find the items as well as improve performance
>      5.  you have to use the AllowUnsafeUpdates before and after your changes
>
>      let me know if I can help further
> ```

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="false">   
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Group Name" HeaderText="Group Name" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="true" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#ad0015">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100px"/>
      </ItemTemplate> 
      </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <HeaderTemplate>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Ok" 
      Width="119px" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
DataTable GetData()
{
    SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPWeb oWeb = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
    SPList oSPList = oWeb.Lists["sample"];
    SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection = oSPList.Items;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Group Name", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("User", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Active", typeof(bool));
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        DataRow dataRow;
        foreach (SPListItem oSplistItem in oSPListItemCollection)
        {
            dataRow = dt.Rows.Add();
            dataRow["Group Name"] = oSplistItem["Group Name"].ToString();
            dataRow["User"] = oSplistItem["User"].ToString();
            dataRow["Section"] = oSplistItem["Section"].ToString();
            dataRow["ID"] = oSplistItem["ID"];
            dataRow["Active"] = oSplistItem["Active"].ToString();

        }
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Managers Approval" + ex.Message.ToString());
        return dt;
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        // Access the CheckBox
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkStatus");
        bool status = cb.Checked;
        string strBoolean = Convert.ToString(status);
                if (cb != null)
                {
                    SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;

                    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList oSPList = oWeb.Lists["sample"];
                        SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection = oSPList.Items;
                        //foreach (SPListItem oSplistItem in oSPListItemCollection)
                        //{
                         int rowId = Int32.Parse(grdList.DataKeys[dr.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

                         SPListItem oSplistItem = oSPList.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(rowId));
                          oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                           {

                            if (strBoolean == "True")
                            {
                                oSplistItem["Active"] = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                oSplistItem["Active"] = false;
                            }
                            oSplistItem.Update();
                        }
                          oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
    }
```

}